# Linux substring, row operations (sed or awk)

Tags: awk, sed, regular-expression

I didn't find a similar example in the forums. reguler_ex don't know.

```
2018-08-15 19:13:48 - 192.168.30.166 Sunucu zamani sorgusu, komut: _POV1D|150|17201|2018|8|15|19|13|1|301|22|305|27|191300|0|225|10|8969|0|0|y|y|y|0|y|y|y|y|y|38930|0|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|*
_POV1D|150|17910|2018|8|15|19|13|1|336|7|349|10|191300|0|290|19|9235|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|*
2018-08-15 19:13:48 - utc|*
2018-08-15 19:13:48 - 192.168.30.166 Sunucu zamani sorgusu, komut: _POV1D|150|17242|2018|8|15|19|13|1|124|34|121|42|191300|0|222|24|8843|0|0|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|32689|0|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|*
2018-08-15 19:13:48 - 192.168.30.166 Sunucu zamani sorgusu, komut: _POV1D|150|17372|2018|8|15|19|13|1|156|49|160|64|191300|0|264|80|9881|y|0|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|28280|0|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|*
_POV1D|150|17205|2018|8|15|19|13|1|0|0|0|2|191300|0|195|52|8319|x|0|y|y|y|x|y|y|y|y|y|x|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|*
2018-08-15 19:13:48 - 192.168.30.166 Sunucu zamani sorgusu, komut: _POV1D|150|17981|2018|8|15|19|13|1|192|22|215|45|191300|0|281|83|10040|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|x|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|*
_POV10D|150|17330|2018|8|15|21|20|2|0|0|0|11|212000|315|341|354|330|308|y|268|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|*
2018-08-15 21:30:49 - 192.168.30.166 Sunucu zamani sorgusu, komut: _POV1D|150|17330|2018|8|15|21|30|1|0|0|0|0|213000|0|271|81|10046|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|x|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|*
_POV10D|150|17979|2018|8|15|23|0|2|326|3|338|9|230000|351|360|357|337|309|y|252|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|*
2018-08-15 21:30:49 - _last|17979|*|*
_POV1D|150|17979|2018|8|15|23|1|1|322|4|323|10|230100|0|262|84|10034|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|x|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|*
```

In rows with _POV, I want to get the line to the end from POV.

Expected Output:

```
_POV1D|150|17201|2018|8|15|19|13|1|301|22|305|27|191300|0|225|10|8969|0|0|y|y|y|0|y|y|y|y|y|38930|0|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|*
_POV1D|150|17910|2018|8|15|19|13|1|336|7|349|10|191300|0|290|19|9235|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|*
_POV1D|150|17242|2018|8|15|19|13|1|124|34|121|42|191300|0|222|24|8843|0|0|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|32689|0|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|*
_POV1D|150|17372|2018|8|15|19|13|1|156|49|160|64|191300|0|264|80|9881|y|0|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|28280|0|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|*
_POV1D|150|17205|2018|8|15|19|13|1|0|0|0|2|191300|0|195|52|8319|x|0|y|y|y|x|y|y|y|y|y|x|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|*
_POV1D|150|17981|2018|8|15|19|13|1|192|22|215|45|191300|0|281|83|10040|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|x|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|*
_POV10D|150|17330|2018|8|15|21|20|2|0|0|0|11|212000|315|341|354|330|308|y|268|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|*
_POV1D|150|17330|2018|8|15|21|30|1|0|0|0|0|213000|0|271|81|10046|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|x|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|*
_POV10D|150|17979|2018|8|15|23|0|2|326|3|338|9|230000|351|360|357|337|309|y|252|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|*
_POV1D|150|17979|2018|8|15|23|1|1|322|4|323|10|230100|0|262|84|10034|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|x|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|y|*
```

With sed and awk I could not. The file is untidy and too long. Can anyone help me.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using grep:

```
grep -o '_POV1D.*' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`:

```
sed 's/^.*_POV/_POV/' file
```

Or, longer but perhaps a little more elegant, avoids the repeated _POV reference

```
sed 's/^.*\(_POV.*\)/\1/' file
```